# org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse below `json` file:

```
{"units":[{"id":42,               
   "title":"Hello World",          
    "position":1,
    "v_id":9,
    "sites":[[{"id":316,
      "article":42,
      "clip":133904
        }],
       {"length":5}]

   }, ..]}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Object obj = null;
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object unitsObj = parser.parse(new FileReader("file.json");
JSONObject unitsJson = (JSONObject) unitsObj;

JSONArray units = (JSONArray) unitsJson.get("units");
Iterator<String> unitsIterator = units.iterator();
while(unitsIterator.hasNext()){         
    Object uJson = unitsIterator.next();
    JSONObject uj = (JSONObject) uJson;
    obj =  parser.parse(uj.get("sites").toString());
    JSONArray jsonSites = (JSONArray)  obj;

    for(int i=0;i<jsonSites.size();i++){
     JSONObject site = (JSONObject)jsonSites.get(i); // Exception happens here.
     System.out.println(site.get("article");
    }
}
```

The code is not working when I try to parse the inner `json array`, so I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

The exception is pointing to this line:

```
JSONObject site = (JSONObject)jsonSites.get(i);
```

Any help? tnx.

Comment: In ``sites`` there seems to be an array in an array, note the double square brackets.

Answer (score 32):

I've found a working code:

```java
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj  = parser.parse(content);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(obj);
```

If you don't need the array (like the author), you can simply use

```java
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj  = parser.parse(content);
```

Comment: Although this is exact opposite to what the question asked, it solved my problem i.e. convert JSONObject to JSONArray...So +1 from my side

Answer (score 8):

The first element of the `sites` array is an array, as you can see indenting the JSON:

```
{"units":[{"id":42,               
    ...
    "sites":
    [
      [
        {
          "id":316,
          "article":42,
          "clip":133904
        }
      ],
      {"length":5}
    ]
    ...
}
```

Therefore you need to treat its value accordingly; probably you could do something like:

```
JSONObject site = (JSONObject)(((JSONArray)jsonSites.get(i)).get(0));
```

Comment: I still get the same exception: `JSONObject cannot be cast to JSONArray`

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps me to know the problem then I solved it by creating a nested loop while `j<site.length()` to get `site.get(j).toString()`

Answer (score 2):

this worked:

```
System.out.println("resultList.toString() " + resultList);
            org.json.JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resultList);
            org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(someField);

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                System.out.println("array is " + jsonArray.get(i));

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObject site=jsonSites.getJSONObject(i)` should work out

Comment: there is no `getJSONObject` method for `JSONArray`

Comment: I'm using this: `org.json.simple.JSON`

Comment: so why don't try the one i introduced?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject obj=(JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(content); 
JSONArray arr=(JSONArray)obj.get("units"); 
System.out.println(arr.get(1));  //this will print {"id":42,...sities ..}
```

@cyberz is right but explain it reverse

Answer (score 1):

You can first read the whole content of file into a String.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
String data="";
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
try{
    fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(filename);
    int i;
    while((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1)
    {
        stringBuffer.append((char)i);
    }
    data = stringBuffer.toString();
}
catch(Exception e){
        LoggerUtil.printStackTrace(e);
}
finally{
    if(fileInputStream!=null){  
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Now You will have the whole content into String ( data variable ).

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonArray= (org.json.simple.JSONArray) parser.parse(data);
```

After that you can use jsonArray as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-filter the json data you can use following method. Given example is getting all document data from couchdb.

```
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String resultJson = restTemplate.getForObject(url+"_all_docs?include_docs=true", String.class);
    JSONObject object =  (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(resultJson);
    JSONArray rowdata = (JSONArray) object.get("rows");   
    List<Object>list=new ArrayList<Object>();   
    for(int i=0;i<rowdata.size();i++) {
        JSONObject index = (JSONObject) rowdata.get(i);
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) index.get("doc");
        list.add(data);      
    }
    // convert your list to json
    String devicelist = gson.toJson(list);
    return devicelist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject site = (JSONObject)jsonSites.get(i); // Exception happens here.
```

The return type of `jsonSites.get(i)` is `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`.
Because sites have two '[', two means there are two arrays here.

Answer (score 0):

use your jsonsimpleobject direclty like below

```
JSONObject unitsObj = parser.parse(new FileReader("file.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject baseReq
LinkedHashMap insert = (LinkedHashMap) baseReq.get("insert");
LinkedHashMap delete = (LinkedHashMap) baseReq.get("delete");
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Comment: I have same code, that convert to `LinkedHashMap`., but suddenly its stop to work and return by get("...") `scala.some.Map`. do you know what can be the problem?